# How to shuffle large scale tfrecord data in Tensorflow adequately?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Assuming that we get 200 thousand pictures labeled '1' and another 200 thousand pictures labeled '0' converted to tfrecord of tensorflow sequentially. And I tried to shuffle the tfrecord with `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`. The question is I can't shuffle the data adequately without an enormous `min_after_dequeue` while it'll be out of memory with a too big `min_after_dequeue`.Is there any solutions to that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `tf.data.Dataset` (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for this purpose, leveraging the `shuffle` transformation and also the `interleave` transformation (assuming you wish to mix the '1' and '0' labels).